# Curvas de acumulación de especies en R

Tags: r

La imagen muestra lo que necesito hacer con mis datos de riqueza.

El código es el siguiente:

```
library (vegan)
data(este)
data(este.env)
attach(este.env)
pool <- specpool(este, Management)
pool
op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(specnumber(este) ~ Management, col="hotpink", border="cyan3",
notch=TRUE)
boxplot(specnumber(este)/specpool2vect(pool) ~ Management, col="hotpink",
border="cyan3", notch=TRUE)
par(op)
data(este)
## Accumulation model
pool <- poolaccum(BCI)
summary(pool, display = "chao")
plot(pool)
## Quantitative model
estimateR(este[1:5,])
```

El punto es que necesito hacer que todos los graficos (4 curvas) esten en uno solo y poder señalar a cada índice (4 índices) con su grafico preferentemente en letra times new roman que es lo que me exige la revista. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Asiel ¿estás cargando alguna librería previo al código que nos compartes? Sería muy importante que lo indiques para intentar reproducir el error. No me parece que `data()` esté cargando un archivo, generalmente se usa para traer al entorno global a datasets que forman parte de paquetes. Aún sin saber bien de cuál es el problema no me parece que lo que necesites sea crear un archivo `.env`

Comment: Si es cierto: library (vegan), es la que llamo mas arriba cierto , el punto es que si no hacia falta el .env, lo que quiero es con ese codigo lograr que todas las figuras me salgan en un mismo grafico, porque asi me salen en graficos separados y señalar dentro del grafico cual índice es cada cual me expliqué?

Comment: El archivo lo exporto directo de un excel sin necesidad de llamar un comando para hacerlo

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta no coincide con tu último comentario. Te sugiero que la edites y agrega un [mcve] para reproducir el problema que mencionas en tu último comentario. Saludos.

Comment: Done!! ya puse la pregunta y el ejemplo verificable

Comment: No logro reproducir el ejemplo, después de instalar `vegan` cuando evalúo `data(este)` recibo un warning `In data(este) : data set ‘este’ not found` ¿Podrías indicar cuál es el origen de esos datos en tu código? ¿Vienen en un paquete o los estás importando? Lo que preguntas del gráfico se puede hacer, pero hacen falta los datos para encontrar una solución.

Comment: Cierto mi error, el : este , lo esty importando desde mi maquina, son datos de la siguiente forma:   a b c d e f g h
sfsffsefs 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
rwerwerw  1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
uopiopuiuo  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
zxvzxcvxccv  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
piopuop  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
wqerewr  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
jkljljk  1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0

Comment: Ya he reformnulado la pregunat con un ejemplo reproducible en este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236357/plotear-varios-graficos-en-uno-solo

Answer (score 1):

> data(este)
>   Warning message:
>   In data(este) : data set ‘este’ not found
>   data(este.env)
>   Warning message:
>   In data(este.env) : data set ‘este.env’ not found

Hola, Asiel, los comentarios no permiten observar tus datos por el formato en el que se imprimieron. Te recomiendo que tu ultimo comentario lo agregues dentro del problema para poder reproducir la data. Aun mejor, si lo agregas con el codigo en R que crea los objetos.