# Plotear varios graficos en uno solo?

Tags: r

Necesito que los cuatros gráficos que salen con el código que les dejo mas abajo salgan en uno solo ajustando la escala lo mejor posible sin perder información y que cada curva sea de un color poniéndole una etiqueta con el nombre del estimado:

Este es el código original

```
library (vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
pool <- with(dune.env, specpool(dune, Management))
pool
op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(specnumber(dune) ~ Management, data = dune.env,
col = "hotpink", border = "cyan3")
boxplot(specnumber(dune)/specpool2vect(pool) ~ Management,
data = dune.env, col = "hotpink", border = "cyan3")
par(op)
data(BCI)
## Accumulation model
pool <- poolaccum(BCI)
summary(pool, display = "chao")
plot(pool)
## Quantitative model
estimateR(BCI[1:5,])
```

Esto es un ejemplo reproducible, asi que no deberán tener problema a la hora de correr el código!!!.

Comment: Estoy viendo el ejemplo, son solo dos gráficos, ¿es correcto?. =Quieres que aparezcan como en una sola página?

Comment: Exacto en una misma pagian pero con la misma escal

Comment: Ahora si ya arregle el codigo aquel lo modifiqué es este el que esta puesto ahora disculpe

Comment: Los graficos lo pueden visualizar en : https://rstudio.cloud/spaces/10382/project/202346

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ver todas las curvas en un solo gráfico, creo que ya nos empieza a convenir pasar todo a `ggplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library (vegan)

data(BCI)
pool <- poolaccum(BCI)

df <- summary(pool) %>% 
    map(as.data.frame) %>%   # Cada matriz de la lista a un data.frame
    map(rename, V = 2) %>%   # Renombramos la 2 columna para que el nombre sea consistente
    bind_rows(.id = "index") # juntamos todos los df en uno solo

ggplot(df, aes(x=N, color=index)) +
    xlab("Size") +
    ylab("Richeness") +
    geom_line(aes(y=V), size=1) +
    geom_line(aes(y=`2.5%`), size=.5, linetype=4) +
    geom_line(aes(y=`97.5%`), size=.5, linetype=4) +
    theme_minimal()
```

El punto clave es transformar el objeto `poolacum` con un poco de gramática de `purrr` y `dplyr` en un único `data.frame` con todos lo índices, para luego explotarlo mediante `ggplot`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece genial la idea aunque me referia a la grafica que dice riqueza poder tener esas 5 curvas en uno solo con la misma escala es posible esto?

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero, ok, verifica mi última edición

Comment: Lo que necesito es que los gráficos de los cinco indices parezcan en uno solo como si estuvieran superpuesto, señalando en el grafico cada índce!! como puedo subir una foto para que entiendas mejor?

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero, a ver, si ahora comprendo. Tienes 5 índices, con 3 líneas, ¿lo que buscas es un solo gráfico con las 15 líneas?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que los graficos de S, Chao, Jacknnife, Jacknnife2, Bootstrap salgan en uno mismo pero diferenciando con una etiqueta cual es cual!!!!!.

Comment: Si sería un solo grafico con 15 líneas, pero diferenciando con una etiqueta a que indice pertence cada uno!!- Si es eso gracias de antemano

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero, ok, verifica la actualización 2

Comment: Genial, otra duda, y si mis datos de riqueza de especies no están asociados a un data.frame o sea puedo poner: data(dune)
pool <- with(dune, specpool(dune), df <- summary(pool) %>% 
    map(dune) %>%

Comment: Bueno en caso de que se pueda, como coloco al grafico el eje x y el eje y que se vea y quito las cuadriculas del fondo?

Comment: Para quitar las grillas, agregale al final `+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())` .  Lo otro, no lo sé, no conozco realmente el paquete `vegan`. Saludos.

Comment: Una ultima cosa como quitar algún índice de los que está graficado por ejemplo jacknife 1? Gracias por toda la ayuda que me estas brindado

Comment: Lo más simple es pasarle a `ggplot` un `data.frame` filtrado sin el índice que deseas, es decir: `ggplot(df[df$index!='jack1',], aes(x=N, color=index)) + ....`

Comment: Me di cuenta de una cosa como puedo ajustar la escala del eje Y y ponerle un límite?

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero, puedes agregar, por ejemplo `+ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20, 40))`

Comment: Disculpe pero me da este error Error: unexpected symbol in:
"     geom_line(aes(y=`97.5%`), size=.5, linetype=4) +
     theme_minimal() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())ggplot"

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero, revisa que 97.5% debe estar encerrado por "backticks", fijate el código original de mi respuesta

Comment: Ya solucionado!!!

Comment: Sabe usted como implemetar triabgle.class..para cambiar el color de los puntos y las lineas interiores en un grafico triangular o usando ggplot este es el enlace de la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235863/cambiar-colores-a-un-grafico-con-plot-ggtern-o-ggplot

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero, la verdad nunca he usado ese paquete.